# Serial.println in arduino ide is not printing properly

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am using nodemcu board ESP8266 1.0 and arduino ide along with it. There is a simple blink light program along with Serial.println code to check both the board and the serial monitor. The board is working fine, but the serial monitor is not giving proper output.

```
 void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
Serial.println("high"); 
delay(1000);             
digitalWrite(13, LOW);    
Serial.println("low");
delay(1000);              
}
```

But the output in the serial monitor is something else, like inverted question mark, some unknown characters.I dont know what is going on, what mistake am i making, please tell me.

Comment: Baud rate mismatch is the usual cause for completely unreadable serial output.  Since you're not specifying a baud rate in your code, I have no idea what rate you should be setting the serial monitor to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you should see the following command:

```
Serial.begin(38400);
```

In the lower right corner of the window that displays the serial print, there is a dropdown that shows some number options. Choose the number that is the same as the number in the code above. That is the baud rate, think of it as the speed at which you communicate. You want to write and read at the same speed so the information gets passed along correctly ;)

Comment: Ok I will try that and report back here. Thank you for the replies

Comment: it worked, thank you so much. it seems that not setting up the baudrate was the issue

Comment: Awesome! Glad i helped, don't forget to vote my answer so that others may see it in case they run into the same problem. Cheers! :D